# Rails locale changing but paths in links stay the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a multilingual application that changes language on a link that it is always at the top of the page.

```
<%= link_to "English", :locale => 'en' %>
<%= link_to "French", :locale => 'fr'  %>
```

When I click on any of the links, the param[:locale] changes, and all the translations appear ok. However, when I click on any url, the link stays with the current locale. It does not change the actual path with the new url.

Controller

```
  before_action :set_locale

  def default_url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale]
  end
```

Routes

```
  namespace :admin do
    scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|fr/ do
        // resources
    end
  end
```

I would like to when I click the link to change locale, everything in the page changes including the paths. Currently it only loads the correct translation file but does not update the paths.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I realised that I have my Admin Controller that extends from Application Controller. I had `before_action :set_locale` in both controllers. For some reason this messed with the language toggle. Not sure why translations load properly but links did not update.

Answer (score 0):

change the routes to

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|fr/ do
  namespace :admin do
    // resources
  end
end
```

it will give you routes like fr fr/admin

then do not forget the route in the view

```
<%=link_to 'English', root_path(locale: 'en') %>
```

or the admin route

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have tried that and unfortunately,  it did not work.

Comment: it would not work, as the there you are redirecting to root. I want it to stay on the same page. I also tried url_for().